# Heatmap : why scaling?

Tags: scale, heatmap

I have to do a heatmap from fold change data. I got a large diversity in the values (for example a few are between 1200 and 500, but the vast majority ot them are below 2). According to what I could read, I suppose I have to "scale" my heatmap but I can't understand why and how it is done. I couldn't find any clear information about it.

To rephrase my question, I don't understand why we have to "scale" the data, is a log2 transfomration not enough ?

Can somebody explain? Thanks

Comment: You should be more specific in your question, maybe adding the language you are referring, a code sample and a more specific question
for further information on how to ask please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry for not having given more details about my data. They are coming from PCR array experiments (3 cell types infected or not by viruses). The fold change values are an output of the Qiagen's "RT2 Profiler PCR Array Data Analysis Webportal".

Comment: A simple "pheatmap" command with my values and a "greenred" color code gave me an almost full lightgreen heatmap with a few red lines. I wanted to send you an image but I couldn't find the way to do it. Indeed a new heatmap with log2FC transformed values helped me to see a few more red and black lines, but the heatmap always contains a lot of lightgreen lines. So I think I will have to scale my data to have a better visualisation. But is there really a biological signification behind this scaling ? How can I relate a scaled-heatmap with a non-scaled one ? It's not totally clear to me.

Comment: I also don't understand the "scaling" effect on my data values. For example the gene that has the highest FC value in one condition and so appears in red in a heatmap without scaling ('redgreen' heatmap color range), now appears in a dark red color in the heatmap with scaling. It seems that the scaling modified this value, lowering it and transforming it in a value close to 0.5 on a 1 to -1 ranging scale (?).

Comment: And it's the same for genes that has a lower FC value that now after scaling got values close to the maximum (which is 1). On the scaled heatmap those gene appears with a very bright red color suggesting gene expression being higher whereas their FC are lower.

I think I quite don't understand the interpretation of "scaled" heatmap whose values are not following FC values and the signification of the ranging from 1 to -1. Could you help me please to interpret them ?

Comment: sorry to ask again my question, but could someone help me to draw a heatmap, tell me what is the best script and above all, why we need to scale the data and how it works?